# Cannot run my flutter app in an emulator: Execution failed for task

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, android-emulator

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 45s

┌─ Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                       │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then │
│ update C:\Users\MSI\AndroidStudioProjects\project\android\build.gradle:                      │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin last stable version actually is **1.6.20** so open *android\build.gradle* file and change line `ext.kotlin_version = //version number` to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.20'
```

Comment: i did but it is not working yet

Comment: Did the error message change? If so, what is the new message?